# working with PHP notice Undefined variable

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii, vagrant

I am trying to fix this for while but I can't. I found several tutorials but I couldn't fix it.

My friend and I are working on the same version, and it works on his PC without any problem - but for me it won't. We are using the same files, I copied mine from him.

What is the matter here and why won't this work on my PC?

Here is my index.php

```
<?php
/* @var $this SystemManagementController */
/* @var $dataProvider CActiveDataProvider */
?>
<?php
$this->breadcrumbs = array(
    Yii::t('mainmenu', 'System Management'),
);

$contentTabUsers = $this->renderPartial('_tab_users', array(
    'model'              => $userModel,
    'columns'            => $userColumns,
    ), $return               = true);
$contentTabStates    = $this->renderPartial('_tab_states', array('model'                     => $stateModel), $return                    = true);
$contentTabPriorities    = $this->renderPartial('_tab_priorities', null, $return                     = true);
$contentTabProperties    = $this->renderPartial('_tab_properties', null, $return                     = true);

$upgradeLog = 'tbd'; //new UpgradeLog();

$systemInfo = new SystemInfo();
try
{
    $systemInfoData = array(
        'System Info'    => $systemInfo->getServerInfo(),
        'Apache'         => $systemInfo->getApacheInfo(),
        'MySQL Info'     => $systemInfo->getMysqlInfo(),
    );
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    Yii::log('Could not retrieve system info, exception thrown with message: ' . $ex->getMessage(), CLogger::LEVEL_ERROR);
    $systemInfoData = array();
}
$contentTabSysinfo = $this->renderPartial('_tab_sysinfo', array(
//  'model'                  => $upgradeLog,
//  'upgradeLogDataProvider' => $this->getUpgradeLogDataProvider(),
//  'upgradeScripts'         => $this->getAllInfoUpgradeScripts(),
    'systemInfo' => $systemInfoData,
    'phpinfo'    => $this->getBasicPhpInfo(),
    ), $return       = true
);




// get the filter value to show max lines
$showMaxLines    = (int) $this->getAppRequest()->getParam('log_show_max_lines', 50);
$contentTabLog   = $this->renderPartial('_tab_log', array(
    'applicationLog' => $this->getLog($showMaxLines),
    'showMaxLines'   => $showMaxLines,
    // 'log_show_max_lines' is a placeholder for the js value in the template
    'filterUrl'      => $this->getYiiApp()->createUrl('systemManagement/index', array('log_show_max_lines' => null)),
    ), $return               = true
);
Yii::app()->user->setState('activeSystemmanagementTab', 'system_info');

$tabs = array();
if (Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('Systemmanagement.users'))
{
    $tabs[Yii::t('systemmanagement', 'Users')] = array('content'     => $contentTabUsers, 'id'       => 'users');
}
if (Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('Systemmanagement.states'))
{
    $tabs[Yii::t('systemmanagement', 'States')] = array('content'    => $contentTabStates, 'id'      => 'states');
}
if (Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('Systemmanagement.priorities'))
{
    $tabs[Yii::t('systemmanagement', 'Priorities')] = array('content'    => $contentTabPriorities, 'id'      => 'priorities');
}
if (Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('Systemmanagement.properties'))
{
    $tabs[Yii::t('systemmanagement', 'Properties')] = array('content'    => $contentTabProperties, 'id'      => 'properties');
}
if (Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('Systemmanagement.sysinfo'))
{
    $tabs[Yii::t('systemmanagement', 'System Info')] = array('content'   => $contentTabSysinfo, 'id'         => 'system_info');
}
if (Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('Systemmanagement.log'))
{
    $tabs[Yii::t('systemmanagement', 'Log')] = array('content'   => $contentTabLog, 'id'         => 'log');
}

$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiTabs', array(
    'tabs'       => $tabs,
    // additional javascript options for the tabs plugin
    'options'    => array(
        'collapsible'    => true,
        'hide'           => 'fade',
        'activeTab'      => Yii::app()->user->getState('activeSystemmanagementTab'),
//      'show'           => 'highlight',
        //TODO @see http://www.bsourcecode.com/2012/11/how-to-handle-cjuitabs-in-yii/
        'selected'       => isset(Yii::app()->session['tabid']) ? Yii::app()->session['tabid'] : 0,
        'select'         => 'js:function(event, ui) {
            var index=ui.index;
            $.ajax({
                "url":"' . Yii::app()->createUrl('site/tabidsession') . '",
                "data":"tab="+index,
            });
    }',
    )
    )
);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeIsactive(id)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('usp/AjaxSetuspOnOff') ?>",
            datatype: 'json',
            data: "MeId=" + id,
            success: function (data) {
                // if page access denied show the error msg
                var hasError = $("<div></div>").append(data).find("#content div.error").length > 0;
                if (hasError)
                {
                    $("#flashmsg").show().addClass('flash-error').html('<?php echo Yii::t('systemwide', 'You Are Not Authorized to Turn On/Off this ELement'); ?>').animate({opacity: 0.9}, 3500).fadeOut("slow");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    if (data != 'error')
                    {
                        if (data)
                        {
                            $('#onOff_' + id).addClass(data);
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#onOff_' + id).removeClass('checked');
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#flashmsg").show().addClass('flash-error').html('<?php echo Yii::t('systemwide', 'You Are Not Authorized to Turn On/Off this ELement'); ?>').animate({opacity: 0.9}, 3500).fadeOut("slow");
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                $("#flashmsg").show().addClass('flash-error').html('<?php echo Yii::t('systemwide', 'You Are Not Authorized to Turn On/Off this ELement'); ?>').animate({opacity: 0.9}, 3500).fadeOut("slow");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

when I go to the server I get this error:

> PHP notice Undefined variable: tabs /var/www/private/protected/views/systemmanagement/index.php(84)

and that is referring to :

```
'tabs'       => $tabs,
```

in order to fix this I added, the following also on top of my file:

```
$tabs = array();
```

Now when I do this, it works and it doesn't give any error, but it just goes to the page and it doesn't show any content. Please help I am spending too much time on this.

if I put this in my code:

> print_r($systemInfoData);

I get:

```
Array ( [System Info] => Array ( [OS] => Linux #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 [Machine Type] => x86_64 [Server Name] => 192.168.33.10 [Server IP Address] => 192.168.33.10 ) [Apache] => Array ( [version] => Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) [Loaded Modules] => core, mod_so, mod_watchdog, http_core, mod_log_config, mod_logio, mod_version, mod_unixd, mod_access_compat, mod_alias, mod_auth_basic, mod_authn_core, mod_authn_file, mod_authz_core, mod_authz_groupfile, mod_authz_host, mod_authz_user, mod_autoindex, mod_cgi, mod_deflate, mod_dir, mod_env, mod_expires, mod_filter, mod_headers, mod_include, mod_mime, prefork, mod_negotiation, mod_php5, mod_reqtimeout, mod_rewrite, mod_setenvif, mod_status ) [MySQL Info] => Array ( [Server version] => 5.5.43-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 [Meta information] => Uptime: 11334 Threads: 1 Questions: 11476 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 76 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 54 Queries per second avg: 1.012 ) )
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82664/discussion-between-jagadeesh-and-alex).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the variable `$tabs` not being defined.

You have two options, as rightly mentioned by the other contributos:

**I. (preferable)**

Define you variable before using it.

**II. (not recommended)**

The error is not shown on your friend's PC because of the `error_reporting` level set in his/her environment. Edit the `error_reporting` level defined in your `php.ini`.

In order to hide the php notices add or edit the following line in the php.ini

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE;
```

Alternatively you can set your error reporting level directly from your script as follows:

```
// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

Read more about error reporting in php here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: When I add this nothng changes,

Comment: This is not the answer.

Comment: I think it was pretty obvious that the error is shown because the variable isn't defined. My answer addresses the difference between environments as mentioned in the question originally.

Comment: That's indeed pretty obvious, but clearly not for the OP who seems to be inexperienced with PHP/programming.

Comment: Edited my answer with addressing both issues.

Comment: The variable not being predefined is an issue, but not his main issue. He has issues with yii authentication. He should not even be seeing that page most likely unless he has propper access rights.

Comment: @n099y I agree, however the authentication problem falls outside the scope of the question.

Comment: @Alex If changing the `error_reporting` in php.ini doesn't do the job, it means that likely it's overwritten in one of you config files.

Comment: @Mark, agreed. OP has received enough input for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the `Undefined variable` error because your `$tabs` variable is not defined.

You have multiple `if` statements that *could* define it, but if they all evaluate to `false`, it will remain undefined.

Setting `$tabs = array();` defines your variable, but it still has no content.

Comment: I was just about to state the same. Your problem is here :
Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('Systemmanagement.users') 
You are not authenticated.

Comment: what do you mean?? You are not authenticated??

Comment: It is checking whether the user has rights to 'Systemmanagement.users' and others. If they do not have rights to any of those, then $tabs will never be set.

Comment: when I do his: $tabs =  false; I get this error: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach(), /vagrant/vendor/yiisoft/yii/framework/zii/widgets/jui/CJuiTabs.php(111)
`

Comment: @Alex, that is because you are trying to iterate over a `boolean` value. A `foreach()` is expecting something such as an array, like `$tabs[] = false`

Comment: @Alex, I won't comment any more after this because you have your answer in mjohns615's answer. You must look out side this one piece of code, I believe you have done something to allow this action to run without having correct access rights and that is the root cause of his problem. look in your controller code and check if you are bypassing authentication for that page. If you want access without authentication, then you need to check the rules on those if statements that are setting the $tabs array.